# How to manage Sticky Content?

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to manage sticky content on front page of website.

I have made five content sticky on top for front page but my query its show by default according to publish date order but I want to fix the order of that sticky content.

Any suggestion or solution about how to do so?

Comment: Your question does not require much effort but you have first to say: How do you display these posts to the front page (views?) and how do you define "my query"?

Answer (score 1):

Enable the "sticky" option within publishing options for 5 of your nodes. Then create a view (using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module) and for this view, within the "Sort criteria" of it, make sure to add  "***Node: Sticky***" as your primary sort criterium (using the Views UI).

When adding this sort criterium to your view, you'll also see "*...To list sticky nodes first, set this to descending.*" (which is what you seem to be looking for).

To finish enter a path for the Views result, and use this path to set it as your frontpage.

Comment: but my question is how to manage from front page  because if i create another sticky on top content and i want manage from front page

Comment: @AnkitGupta : sorry to say, but the question in your previous comment is another question. And changing the question content after it was answered is not allowed on this site (because it would invalidate existing answers). Instead you should post this new question (in your prior comment) as a "followup question", if you want with a link to this question.